# What effect does a negation have on a proposition in a bracket.

Tags: logic

Say for example ¬ (p ∧ ¬q}, what does the negation outside the bracket do to the proposition inside the bracket?

Answer (score 1):

Negation has a few effects. For this example $\lnot (p \land \lnot q)$ becomes $(\lnot p \lor q)$.

Comment: No worries! The general rule is $\lnot(p\land q) \equiv \lnot p \lor \lnot q$ and $\lnot(p\lor q) \equiv \lnot p \land \lnot q$